# How to autocreate a valid xml structure giving only a dtd DOCTYPE VSCODE

Tags: xml, dtd

I would like to know if I can make a valid xml structure giving only one dtd DOCTYPE at vscode, for example:
    `<!DOCTYPE productos [ <!ELEMENT produtos (produto+)> <!ELEMENT produto (nome, descricion, prezo)> <!ATTLIST produto codigo ID #REQUIRED> <!ELEMENT nome (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT descricion (#PCDATA)> <!ELEMENT prezo (#PCDATA)> ]>`

I have installed the Red Hat XML extension.

Im expecting to get a valid xml structure as fast as posible, maybe automatically with some feature that I didnt know yet. Thank you.

Comment: The DTD seems inconsistent, if there is e.g. `DOCTYPE productos`, there should be declaration for that `productos` root element but there is only one for an element spelled `produtos`.